# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. appears when select any row from the gridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have 2 forms.. `gridForm` has a `dataGridView` gets its data from database, the second form `editForm`has `textboxes` similar to the `gridView Columns`.

i want to select a row in the `grid` then click an edit button and the `editForm` must shown and the textboxes have the values from grid

**gridForm**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            // when i put this line only , it works right.
            edditContactForm.edditContactNameSetter = row.Cells["contactNameGridViewColumn"].Value.ToString();

            // this also with the previous is working right too.
            edditContactForm.edditJobTitleSetter = row.Cells["jobTitleGridViewColumn"].Value.ToString();

            // the problem appears here and the exhibition shown to this line and any similar lines under it. 
            edditContactForm.edditCompanyNameSetter = row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**editForm:**

```
    public string edditContactNameSetter 
    {
        set { txtContactName.Text = value; }
    }

    public string edditJobTitleSetter
    {
        set { txtJobTitle.Text = value; }
    }

    public string edditCompanyNameSetter
    {
        set { txtCompanyName.Text = value; }
    }
```

**exhibition:**

The exhibition appers when i select any row from the grid
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a column with `CompanyNameGridViewColumn` ?

Comment: It seems that the `row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"].Value` is null.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Try checking to see if it has a value before you convert it to a string with ToString()

Comment: how can i ensure if its value is null or not

Comment: I think part of your problem here is that your naming conventions aren't consistent.  You have some 'someVariableName' and some 'OtherVariableName'.  Likely, that is your problem.  As Hamlet mentioned above, `row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"].Value` is (most likely) `null`.

Comment: @Mahmoud - set a breakpoint at `edditContactForm.edditCompanyNameSetter = row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"].Value.ToString();` and inspect the value of it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I still can't solve the problem.. is `row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"].Value` is null that means it is not get values from database or something else??....... i don't get the real meaning of `null` ..

Comment: `row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"]` may be null by itself, meaning there is no column with that name.

Comment: @JohnSaunders i've take it copy/paste from `Columns: (Collection)` property

Comment: Use the debugger! Stop before the error and see what's in `row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found the problem, and since i am a newbie in c#, i think it's a naive mistake for professionals.

the problem was in the `SELECT FROM` query, i just didn't select the `companyName` values from database, so the `row.Cells["CompanyNameGridViewColumn"].Value` gets `null`.